# Setting value of parameter containing " ' " (apostrophe) used in LIKE query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following query in ASP.NET/C# code which is failing to return any values using a parameter...

```
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE @search
```

I have tried the following query alternatives to set this parameter in SQL commands...

```
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE  %@search%
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE '%@search%'
```

And through the api...

```
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", search);
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + search + "%");
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%'" + search + "'%");
```

None of those work.

The search parameter I am using has single quotes in its text which I think is making things even more awkward.  I believe I am escaping the parameter correctly because if I construct a query which uses the value directly as opposed to through parameters like so...

```
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE '%MyValue''ToSearchForWith''Quotes%'
```

That works.  From what I have seen all you need to do to have single quotes in your query is to double them up.  I have not seen any errors so I am assuming I've got this correct.  So worst case I have a solution but I would like to be setting the search value through the api as I believe this is better practice.

Comment: @Rob Segal: Can you explain "None of those work"? It looks like the ones in the middle, respectively, are fine. Can it be there actually *is* no record that matches your test criterion? Or does it throw an error of some sort?

Comment: What is the value in the search variable?  Did you pre-delimit the ' char as ''?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're escaping the quotes in your `search` parameter, when the SQL parameter does that for you.

The percent signs should be *inside* the SQL Parameter value; your query just references the parameter plainly.  The SQL should look like this:

```
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE @search
```

And the code should look like this:

```
string search = "MyValue'ToSearchForWith'Quotes";
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + search + "%");
```

Note that `search` is the *original* value, not escaped.

Comment: I think you get the code right, but the SQL should be LIKE '%' + @search + '%'

Comment: This was exactly it.  I was escaping the single quote parameter value before inserting that value through the API.  Note that for the query I didn't need the %'s around the @search parameter as they are being included in the call to AddWithValue.  Thanks very much for the reply though.  Works great now.

Answer (score 3):

On the SQL side, this is correct:

```
select * from MyTable where MyTable.name LIKE '%' + @search + '%'
```

If the parameter was passed in from outside, it would not matter if it contained single quotes.

On the API side, this should be correct:

```
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search", "%" + search + "%");
```

The AddWithValue() method does all the necessary escaping for you, no need to interfere.

Answer (score 0):

within t-sql you escape '  by using two:  ''

@query='  this doesn''t cause a problem'