# SQLexception Incorrect syntax near ##

Tags: c#, sqlexception

I'm getting a sqlexception while im trying to select some values.
The error: Incorrect syntax near '@navn'. I've looked around to find other questions similar to mine, but I can't find anything worth to me.

My code:

```
public List<Vare> findvareAdvanced(string varenavn)
    {
        Vare v = new Vare();
        List<Vare> lv = new List<Vare>();

        SqlConnection myCon = DBcon.getInstance().conn();

        string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Vare WHERE Navn LIKE %@navn%");

        myCon.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, myCon);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("navn", varenavn);
        SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            v.Stregkode = dr.GetString(0);
            v.Navn = dr.GetString(1);
            v.Pris = dr.GetDecimal(2);
            v.Varegruppenr = dr.GetInt32(3);
            lv.Add(v);

        }
        myCon.Close();




        return lv;
    }
```

Comment: See the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664314/c-constructing-paramater-query-sql-like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
 string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Vare WHERE Navn LIKE @navn");

 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@navn", "%" + varenavn + "%");
```

Comment: +1 for thinking about what he was actually trying to do. You could also add `WHERE Navn LIKE ('%' + @navn + '%')` to your answer; for the case where he can't change the parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a literal translation of the string, add an `@` symbol before the string.  This will help handle escape characters

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859080/setting-value-of-paramter-containing-apostrophe-used-in-like-query) question might also help

```
string query = string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Vare WHERE Navn LIKE %@navn%");
```

Answer (score 0):

forgot the ' ?

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Vare WHERE Navn LIKE '%@navn%' ");
```