# Create a static method that will parse any string to detect special characters and include \ before them

Tags: c#, regex, string

In my MVC-App I want to create a method that will be used everywhere to avoid having any special characters like @, ", ' or anything else provoking a major problem.

So I'm trying to build this method using a regex that parses a string to detect if there's any special characters in the string and put a \ in front of them to make them harmless.

```
public static string ParseStringForSpecialChars(string stringToParse)
{
     const string regexItem = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$";

     string stringToReturn = Regex.Replace(stringToParse, regexItem, "\\");

     return stringToReturn;
}
```

There are many problems in my code:
1) I am not familiar with regex and I have troubles figuring out what I wanted to do. Here, I think I was trying to detect if there were any characters other than thos in the regexItem; 2) When the code hits the `string stringToReturn =` line, my app crashed as it says that the value cannot be null.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

**EDIT**

I have been asked to show an example of special characters, here they are:

`'/', '.', '*', '+', '?', '|', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '\\'`

You get the idea, I just want to avoid sending a string to the database containing a ', because that will be interpreted as then end of a string and will provoke an error.

Comment: There is an `Escape` method for this...

Comment: @ToonCasteele do you mean `Regex.Escape`? That won't escape `@` for instance - it only escapes regex meta-characters, but the set of characters that the OP wants to escape seem to have nothing to do with regex.

Comment: An escape method? How does it works? And as @m.buettner mentioned, I want to make sure every special characters are trapped by this behavior to avoid problems later on.

Comment: And I don't want to "remove" those special characters, rather put a \ in front of them to render them harmless.

Comment: Harmless in what context? What would be the problem with an "@" for example?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know, because I also don't know if a string containing @ can do any "harm" or be read badly in a sql server string.

Comment: You need to make clear what characters you want escaped

Comment: OK. So we're talking about reading and writing to SQL? Or was that just an example?

Comment: Just an example. @ToonCasteele, ok, I will add up the special characters I want to detect in my post up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're worried about writing to sql, check out:
[SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

As for your code, I think this is it:

```
public static string ParseStringForSpecialChars(string stringToParse)
{
    const string regexItem = "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]";

    string stringToReturn = Regex.Replace(stringToParse, regexItem, @"\$&");

    return stringToReturn;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the point, I just want to parse incoming strings to format them before sending them to the database. Nice advice tho.

Comment: @HerveS I wasn't clear enough. This method actually escapes all data so it won't create any trouble with sql. For example: if you get a user's input and want to store it, but are afraid a malicious user might enter information like `Drop Table` - this method will escape that. As far as I know(! Might be worth double checking.)

Comment: @HerveS I saw your edit. As far as I know - the method I linked to will avoid any problems like the one you mentioned. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/859140/939213 .

Comment: This seems to work, but does not cover everything. I will edit my post up there to explain furthermore.

Comment: Ah, after a bit of work, I have found out why. I needed to add more special characters, like this: `@"\$%&'"`, and now it works :)